# Localhost not accessible with VPN

Tags: tomcat, localhost, vpn

Whenever I get connected to VPN, I have observed that my localhost becomes in-accessible.

I have a local tomcat server and I want to execute my web application on this tomcat server, while being connected with VPN.

However, doing so, the browser redirects the localhost to some other IP.

Please help

Comment: Try connecting using 127.0.0.1.  What OS?

Comment: OS is: Windows 7 and 127.0.0.1 is also not working

Comment: What does your routing table look like before the VPN connect? After?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, that "some other IP" is the IP your machine has been assigned connecting with your VPN connection. If you set your Tomcat server to host applications from that IP which is the "Host name" under the Tomcat general information section (double clicking on the server in Eclipse displays this info) everything should work OK. It worked for me anyway.

[image]